# C# Set default download directory chrome WebDriver?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my solution, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824996/how-to-set-chrome-preferences-using-selenium-webdriver-net-binding)

But it's not working, I need to change the default download directory for google chrome to

> C:\temp\

Thanks for the help.

```cs
public class ChromeOptionsWithPrefs : ChromeOptions
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> prefs { get; set; }
}

public static void Initialize()
{
    var options = new ChromeOptionsWithPrefs
    {
        prefs = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"download.default_directory", @"C:\temp\"}
        }
    };
    
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\chromedriver_win32\", options);
    
    var download = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[.='Download']"));
    
    foreach (var t in download)
    {
        t.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
    }
}
```

I found this solution, it worked

```cs
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"D:\DataTest");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\chromedriver_win32\", chromeOptions);

var download = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[.='ダウンロード']"));

foreach (var t in download)
{
    t.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

Comment: you don't give your answers in the question. Just add it as a answer..

Comment: duplicate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434443/download-file-at-custom-path-using-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just pasting the answer that OP found, but did not add as an answer.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"D:\DataTest");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\chromedriver_win32\", chromeOptions);
var download = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//a[.='ダウンロード']"));

foreach (var t in download)
{
    t.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

These settings worked for me

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
var downloadDirectory = "C:\Temp";

chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

var driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not best, may be even not good way to to it, but maybe will help if you didn't find other answers helpful. It works for me:

```
private static ChromeOptions options()
{
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"path");
    chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);

    return chromeOptions;
    }
     
protected static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options());
```

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"path");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
```

thanks