# Selenium C# - Chrome Driver doesn't download files on headless mode

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the 77th version of chrome to test some downloads. But I don't understand why it doesn't let download files on headless mode (Only happens on headless mode). This is the code I'm using.

_chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"Directory Folder");
                _chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
                _chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
                _webdriver = new ChromeDriver(_chromeOptions);

Answer (score 4):

I was able to download files in headless mode using the following ChromeOptions :

```
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--headless");
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", ApplicationSettings.StagingDirectory);
            chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

**Chrome Version** - 89.0.4389

**Chrome Driver Version** - 89.0.4389.2300

Answer (score 1):

This function returns headless Chrome browser instance with automatic download set to "USERPROFILE" Downloads folder. You can hardcode the download folder you wish.

Call function GetBrowserWebDriver("Chrome") from the test initializer

```
public IWebDriver GetBrowserWebDriver(string browser)
        {
            IWebDriver currentDriver = null;        
            switch (browser)
            {
                case "Chrome":                    
                    var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    options.AddArgument("headless");
                    string downloadPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads";
                    options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
                    options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
                    options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");                    
                    currentDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                    break;
                case "Firefox":
                    currentDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                case "IE":
                    currentDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(new InternetExplorerOptions() { IgnoreZoomLevel = true });
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("");
            }
            return currentDriver;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative, you can download files using Firefox headless browser.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Windows\\temp");
profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream");
options.setProfile(profile);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: If you persist on using chrome, look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33435817/10515117

Comment: Yeah, I'm using those solutions but still doesn't let me. I have to download it on chrome is mandatory

Answer (score 0):

Downloading of files is disabled in Chrome Headless mode by default. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

You need to make an API call to the driver to enable it.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
// Allow download in headless mode
var param = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"behavior", "allow"}, {"downloadPath", DownloadPath}
};
var cmdParam = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior"}, {"params", param}};
var url = driverService.ServiceUrl + "session/" + driver.SessionId + "/chromium/send_command";
var cli = new WebClient {Headers = {[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json"}};
_ = cli.UploadString(url, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cmdParam));
```