# Headless Python Selenium MacOS to Click/Download Documents via Chromium

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

There's a lot on this topic. However, I have found nothing **workable** so far that involves using what is said in the title above and configurations listed below.

Here is what I am attempting to do: go to this [webpage](http://webapps.rrc.texas.gov/eds/eds_searchUic.xhtml) and click on the csv document icon for download (via xpath or css selectors). Either icon is fine - they download the same content.

The sourcecode below outlines what I have done so far. This script runs with no issues, but no document is downloaded - how do I possibly resolve this issue?

Note the following parameters for OS, Python, ChromeDriver, and Chrome configurations:

*macOS Mojave v.10.14.6, Python v.3.7.3, ChromeDriver v.770386540, Chrome v.770386540*

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

prefs = {"download.default_directory": "SOME_PATH"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.binary_location = 'PATH_TO_CHROME'
options.add_argument('headless')

# set the window size
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')

# initialize the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('PATH_TO_CHROME_DRIVER',
                          options=options)

page_url = 'http://webapps.rrc.texas.gov/eds/eds_searchUic.xhtml'
button = '//*[@id="SearchUicForm:searchTable_paginator_top"]/a[7]'

driver.get(page_url)

# wait up to 10 seconds for the elements to become available
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(button).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can comment this line of code `options.add_argument('headless')` and see what is happening in browser. It basically clicks the cvs icon and a download window pop up in browser so we need to handle this pop up window in order to download. We can add chrome options to prevent this.

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\xxx\downloads\Test",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": True
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: I haven't tested yet but if it doesn't work and using Firefox won't be a problem then see my other tested answer [my stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271062/10515117)

Comment: thanks for the input but "AddUserProfilePreference" is not a method - is there some other functionality you may be referring to?

Comment: I have edited the answer for python. Sorry for not focusing on language.